# How do you pass parameters to Azure Logic Apps Liquid Connector for JSON-JSON transformation?

Tags: json, azure-logic-apps, connector, dotliquid

I have a Liquid transformation step in my Azure Logic App, using the "Transform JSON to JSON" version of the Liquid connector. I need to pass some parameters into the transformation - these values will end up in the JSON output from the transformation.

Unfortunately, I can't find any documentation or examples on how you would pass such parameters into the Liquid map.

Comment: Sadly I have not worked much with Liquid yet so I only have the suggestion with adding properties via the expressions language. While i understand that this is not really what you are looking for., `AddProperty(object,property','value')`, `SetProperty(object,property','value')` or `RemoveProperty(object,property','value')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to specifically 'pass parameters' to a Liquid template because Liquid does not support that construct.

However, you can easily inject a Parameters object into the source JSON using the Compose Action.  Then you access them like any other value.

Comment: Good suggestion - I've tried this workaround and it does the job. My only concern is that with this in place, the Liquid map is no longer mapping the true incoming object: it's mapping a hybrid object that contains the parameters and the json object that needs to be re-mapped.

Comment: Well, my response to that would be...and?  So what?  :)  What matters is the output, not the 'purity' of the input.  Consider, simple Inheritance changes the nature of the original and everyone's been fine with that for decades.

Comment: yes, there shouldnt be any concern for having to do an extra transformation - dont forget that the power of a transform is that it is pure by definition: _given the same input, we will always arrive at the same output_ do as many transforms as you want, they are clean and very explicitly defined